# JSF Panels positioning

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am able to set my panel's position then update it however I have trouble when getting its current position.

For example:
Currently, my panel is positioned at (50, 50).

```
 <h:form id="testForm">
        <p:panel id="pane" style="position: absolute; left:50px; top:50px;">
            <p:panelGrid columns=4>
                <p:outputPanel id="ASlot3" styleClass="slot"/>  
                <p:outputPanel id="ASlot4" styleClass="slot"/>  
                <p:outputPanel id="ASlot5" styleClass="slot"/>  
                <p:outputPanel id="ASlot6" styleClass="slot"/>  
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
        <p:draggable id="drg" for="pane"/>

        <p:commandButton id="press" action="#{sbean.press}"/>

    </h:form>
```

I update its position via dragging the panel. After dragging it, I press a button holding this method printing the contents of "style".

```
    //press() method
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
    UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("testForm").findComponent("pane");

    Panel p = (Panel) component;

    System.out.println(p.getAttributes().get("style"));
```

The "style" does not update after dragging the panel and pressing the button.

So how can I get my panel's current position after dragging?

EDIT: BTW, the scope I'm using is @ViewScoped

Comment: it probably shouldn't make a difference but have you tried binding the component directly to the bean?

Comment: @kolossus that might actually work and be a lot easier.

Comment: @Francis create and initialise a member variable in your backing bean of the type of component you wish to bind e.g. `Panel myPanel = new Panel()`(don't forget getter and setter). Then add `binding=#{myBean.myPanel}` on your view-side component. All further interactions you wish to do with the component in the backing bean should now be with the `myPanel` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the PrimeFaces `commandButton` component operates with Ajax functionality, meaning that for the form submit to process the component with id `pane` you would need to declare that in the `process` attribute.

```
<p:commandButton id="press" action="#{sbean.press}" process="@this pane"
  update="@this pane" />
```

The other option is to simply process and update the whole form.

```
<p:commandButton id="press" action="#{sbean.press}" process="@form"
  update="@form" />
```

Or you can simply set Ajax functionality to Off and it will operate like a typical form submit control.

```
<p:commandButton id="press" action="#{sbean.press}" ajax="false" />
```

**EDIT:** I see though that the Primefaces draggable does not update the absolute position of the component to the server's View State.  This is unfortunate but it can be worked around using hiddenInputs and a Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updatePanelPosition() {
    var panel = jQuery('#testForm\\:pane');
    var hiddenLeftInput = jQuery('#testForm\\:hiddenLeft');
    var hiddenTopInput = jQuery('#testForm\\:hiddenTop');
    var left = panel.css('left');
    var top = panel.css('top');
    hiddenLeftInput.val(left);
    hiddenTopInput.val(top);
  }
</script>

<h:inputHidden id="hiddenLeft" value="#{viewScopedBean.leftProperty}" />
<h:inputHidden id="hiddenTop" value="#{viewScopedBean.topProperty}" />

<p:commandButton id="press" action="#{sbean.press}" process="@form"
   update="@form" onstart="updatePanelPosition()" />
```

The two hidden input components will get updated with the current left and top property of `pane` just before the submit, and then those values will get updated to managed bean properties where you will be able to fetch the values.

I know it seems messy but in the end this is really what the managed bean is good for, acting like a view controller and containing presentation logic.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it seems that my panel goes back to its original position after clicking the button. The output of my printing in the press() method is still my initial style values

`position: absolute; left:50px; top:50px;`

Comment: @Francis Ahh I was under the impression that the Primefaces Draggable took care of updating the server side style attribute but apparently not.  I posted an edit above.

Comment: May I ask what `inputHidden` is for? If I place it with my code, my button does not call the method but if I remove it, the button calls the method. How about that `leftProperty` and `topProperty`? Just to be sure. :)

Comment: The `inputHidden` components are additional form fields that will be submitted when you click the button.  The `leftProperty` and `topProperty` are additional managed bean properties that you will have to add to your code. When you click the button, the new managed bean properties will have the appropriate values for left and top respectively when the action method is called.

Comment: Oh ok. Now it's clear. Thank you for this. This is gonna help me a lot. :D